# How g_key_file_get_string() works?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, glib

I can't understand how this function return string as `gchar*`.

Does it dynamically allocates memory inside for string storage? So, in this case it is possible memory leak ?

```
typedef char gchar;

gchar *g_key_file_get_string(GKeyFile *key_file,
                              const gchar *group_name,
                              const gchar *key,GError **error)
```

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: That's not C++. Apart from that: what does the documentation say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html#g-key-file-get-string) says:

> Returns: a **newly allocated** string or NULL if the specified key cannot be found.

So yes, the function internally allocates memory and you should free the memory after use in order to prevent a memory leak.

As a general rule of thumb, the GLib functions tend to return `gchar *` if they want you to free something, or `const gchar *` if they don't.